# Css style for SelectionCell

Tags: css, gwt

I'm currently working with GWT 2.3 on a new project. I'm using several CellTable and I wanted to update the display. I have used a interface in order to redefine the CellTable.css. It works for the simple row (for example TextCell) but it doesn't work for special cell like SelectionCell.

Do you know how to access the style of this element ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own implementation. Mine is based on the GWT source code of `SelectionCell`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gwt.cell.client.AbstractInputCell;
import com.google.gwt.cell.client.ValueUpdater;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.NativeEvent;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.SelectElement;
import com.google.gwt.safehtml.client.SafeHtmlTemplates;
import com.google.gwt.safehtml.client.SafeHtmlTemplates.Template;
import com.google.gwt.safehtml.shared.SafeHtml;
import com.google.gwt.safehtml.shared.SafeHtmlBuilder;

public class StyledSelectionCell extends AbstractInputCell<String, String> {

    interface Template extends SafeHtmlTemplates {
        @Template("<option value=\"{0}\">{0}</option>")
        SafeHtml deselected(String option);

        @Template("<option value=\"{0}\" selected=\"selected\">{0}</option>")
        SafeHtml selected(String option);
    }

    private static Template template;

    private final HashMap<String, Integer> indexForOption = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    private final List<String> options;

    private String style;

    public StyledSelectionCell(List<String> options) {
        super("change");
        if (template == null) {
            template = GWT.create(Template.class);
        }
        this.options = new ArrayList<String>(options);
        int index = 0;
        for (String option : options) {
            indexForOption.put(option, index++);
        }
    }

    public StyledSelectionCell(List<String> options, String style) {
        super("change");
        this.style = style;
        if (template == null) {
            template = GWT.create(Template.class);
        }
        this.options = new ArrayList<String>(options);
        int index = 0;
        for (String option : options) {
            indexForOption.put(option, index++);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent, String value,
            NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater) {
        super.onBrowserEvent(context, parent, value, event, valueUpdater);
        String type = event.getType();
        if ("change".equals(type)) {
            Object key = context.getKey();
            SelectElement select = parent.getFirstChild().cast();
            String newValue = options.get(select.getSelectedIndex());
            setViewData(key, newValue);
            finishEditing(parent, newValue, key, valueUpdater);
            if (valueUpdater != null) {
                valueUpdater.update(newValue);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void render(Context context, String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
        // Get the view data.
        Object key = context.getKey();
        String viewData = getViewData(key);
        if (viewData != null && viewData.equals(value)) {
            clearViewData(key);
            viewData = null;
        }

        int selectedIndex = getSelectedIndex(viewData == null ? value
                : viewData);
        if (style != null && !"".equals(style)) {
            String html = "<select tabindex=\"-1\" class=\"" + style + "\">";
            sb.appendHtmlConstant(html);
        } else {
            sb.appendHtmlConstant("<select tabindex=\"-1\">");
        }
        int index = 0;
        for (String option : options) {
            if (index++ == selectedIndex) {
                sb.append(template.selected(option));
            } else {
                sb.append(template.deselected(option));
            }
        }
        sb.appendHtmlConstant("</select>");
    }

    private int getSelectedIndex(String value) {
        Integer index = indexForOption.get(value);
        if (index == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        return index.intValue();
    }

}
```